# How to select the range of all values until the end under row 3?

Tags: excel, vba, range

```
Set Data = range(Cells(3, 1), .End(xlDown).End(xlToRight)).Select
```

Comment: Would you really need to select a range? Usually bad practice and can be avoided most of times.

Comment: How would you go about it?

Comment: Depends what your purpose is, why are you selecting this range?

Comment: I am trying to name another range referring to the Data below row 3 until the end of the sheet

Answer (score 0):

```
dim Data as range

with ActiveSheet.Cells(3, 1)
    Set Data = range(.End(xlToRight), .End(xlDown))
    Data.Select
end with
```